# How do I specify multiple Join Conditions with $lookup in ReactiveMongo aggregation framework?

Tags: mongodb, scala, aggregation-framework, reactivemongo

How do I specify multiple Join Conditions with $lookup in ReactiveMongo (0.17.1) with the following in mind? - as per [the mongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup).

**users collection**

```
[
    {
      "name": "dogfrey",
      "field": "cowboy"
    },
    {
      "name": "catsville",
      "field": "spaceman"
    }
]
```

**roles collection**

```
[
    {
      "id": 0,
      "userType": "cowboy",
      "spaceman": "fiver",
      "num": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "userType": "joker",
      "spaceman": "tenner",
      "num": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "userType": "cowboy",
      "spaceman": "tenner",
      "num": 1
    }
]
```

**MongoDb query**

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "name": "dogfrey"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "roles",
      let: {
        "users_field": "$field"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$userType",
                "$$users_field"
              ]
            },
            
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "dogs"
    }
  }
])
```

[See here for the MongoPlayground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_lcQLOBlsay)

The [ReactiveMongo documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.1x/documentation/advanced-topics/aggregation.html#lookup) doesn't include any such examples suggesting that it may not be possible. Any help appreciated!

---

Also just to add something that I have tried (unsuccessfully):

```
  def getResults(aColl: JSONCollection, bColl: JSONCollection)
                (id: BSONObjectID)(implicit request: Request[AnyContent]) = aColl.aggregateWith[JsObject]() {
    framework => import framework.{Match, Lookup, AddFields, Project, Sort, Ascending, Descending, Filter, Limit, Group, Sum, Push, Slice}

    ...

    val lookupJso = Lookup(
      from = bColl.name,
      let = Json.obj("fromDate" -> "$varData_e.plan_e.when_e.fromDate", "toDate" -> "$varData_e.plan_e.when_e.toDate"),
      pipeline = Json.arr(
        "$match" -> Json.obj("$expr" ->
            Json.obj("$and" -> Json.arr(
              Json.obj("$gte" -> Json.arr("$varData_e.dateTime", f"$$fromDate")),
              Json.obj("$lt" -> Json.arr("$varData_e.dateTime", f"$$toDate"))
            )),
         ),
        "$project" -> Json.obj("_id" -> 0)
      ),
      "temp_e.lookupTest1_e"
    )

    ...

  }.collect[List](Int.MaxValue, Cursor.FailOnError[List[JsObject]]())
```

I can see that the `Lookup case class` looks like this:

```
  case class Lookup(
    from: String,
    localField: String,
    foreignField: String,
    as: String) extends PipelineOperator {
    import builder.{ document, elementProducer => element, string }
    val makePipe: pack.Document = document(Seq(
      element(f"$$lookup", document(Seq(
        element("from", string(from)),
        element("localField", string(localField)),
        element("foreignField", string(foreignField)),
        element("as", string(as)))))))
  }
```

Comment: What have you already tried by yourself? Which version?

Comment: @cchantep thanks for the response. The ReactiveMongo version is 0.17.1 and I've added more detail to the question. With thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Release 0.17.1 is more than one year old (latest version being the [major 1.0](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/1.0/documentation/release-details.html)).

You can see in the [documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.1x/documentation/advanced-topics/agg-custom-stage.html) it's possible to define raw aggregation operator for stage not provided convenient factory in the API.

```scala
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

import reactivemongo.bson._
import reactivemongo.api.collections.bson.BSONCollection

def customAgg(coll: BSONCollection)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) =
  coll.aggregateWith[BSONDocument]() { framework =>
    import framework.{ Match, PipelineOperator, Project }

    val lookup = PipelineOperator(BSONDocument(f"$$lookup" -> BSONDocument(
      "from" -> "roles",
      "let" -> BSONDocument("users_field" -> f"$$field"),
      "pipeline" -> Seq(
        Match(BSONDocument(f"$$expr" ->
          BSONDocument(f"$$eq" -> Seq(f"$$userType", f"$$$$users_field")))).
          makePipe,
        Project(BSONDocument("_id" -> 0)).makePipe),
      "as" -> "dogs")))

    Match(BSONDocument("name" -> "dogfrey")) -> List(lookup)
  }
```